# How to give to a client specific ip address in Casablanca (CPP Rest SDK)

Tags: c++, sockets, ip-address, casablanca, cpprest-sdk

I have multiple NIC cards in my machine. One of them is a static IP and the other one isn't. However, they both have access to the Internet. 

Is there a way to force the CPP Rest SDK (Casablanca) to use the static IP address instead of the non-static IP?

I came across IP binding in the following: [How to give to a client specific ip address in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673846/how-to-give-to-a-client-specific-ip-address-in-c)

I would like to do that same type of IP binding using the CPP Rest SDK.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem will be solved with this points:
at first you have to run your code with administrator privilege.
and second define you http_listener this way:

```
http_listener m_listener_(L"http://YOUR_STATIC_IP:port/")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response ... though I'll be honest over the past 2 years I have moved away from using Casablanca (primarily, but not solely for this reason). As such I will not bother to validate whether or not this solution would work.